# Creating a ConvexGeometry hangs the page, in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, computational-geometry, convex-hull

I want to create a convex geometry hull around a geometry with lots of vertices to make collision detection/ray casting easier. But when I add above 60 vertices to the ConvexGeometry the page hangs.

Is this not possible to do or have I missed something?
Does anyone know of any better way to handle this?

Here's parts of my code.

```
var x, y, z, max = 1.0,min = 0.1,points = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) { // <-- alter this value above 60- hangs the page
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    z = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    points.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z));
}
var geometry = new THREE.ConvexGeometry(points);
```

Here's a fiddle with the rest. It will not hang your page :)

http://jsfiddle.net/arpo/e45zhryk/

Comment: I achieved inconsistent results when trying to discern a pattern, but using 20 points usually resulted in over 100 faces. 40 points created thousands of faces. 50 points weighed in at over 10000 faces (one test I saw 37k). With this growth in mind, imagine how many faces would be created using 60 points. To put it simply, that is A LOT for a single geometry. Without knowing more about the inner workings of ConvexyGeometry's generation engine, I would suggest that it is not recommended to use so many points. Perhaps you could further simplify your hull?

Comment: Yes your right. I found a library called Quick hull that's quick but sometimes gives a bit broken geometries. Maybe I have to write my one method. Here's Quick hull running in real time.
http://www.mark-lundin.com/quickhull/